# Apply for Schengen visitor visa with trip to UK before UK visa is approved

Tags: visas, uk, schengen-visas, passport-stamps

I am about to apply for a Schengen short stay visa to Spain.

Previously when I've applied for a schengen visa, the question on the form has been: "do you have a visa for your exit country". This is complicated:

1. I am traveling to and from my home country, so (obviously) I have a visa for the end of my trip.
2. Half way through my trip I am visiting the UK. I do not (yet) have a visa for the UK, I am applying concurrently at UK and Spain visa offices using the "keep my passport" option in the UK visa application process.

How do I answer the question on the form? Do I say "yes" because the last destination is my home country? Or do I say "no" and make a comment about the UK visa?

I don't think I can choose to just not list the UK trip, or I will have no reason for the multiple entry option that I will need.

Answer (score 1):

No need to get yourself worked up into a twist over this question. You can answer either way and include a short writeup of your travel plans which explains your itinerary.

Although application forms are designed to be clear and comprehensive and many times to have binary answers, the questions cannot cover every single scenario.

You can also explain at the interview you will be interviewed.